# Excel VBA: Copy filename in cell after last row with data and skip files that already exists

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that works as is. I select a folder and it copies the file names into a table starting on A2 and creates hyperlinks. Right now it just overwrites everything when I select a folder again. I am trying to modify it so that it skip ones it already added, and insert new items into the row after the last row with data. Any advice on how to write that would be appreciated.

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function    

Sub FileLinks()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim sItem As String
Dim Last As Long

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "S:\ACCOUNTING\Subcontracts\"
    If .Show = -1 Then
    'ok clicked
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    Else
    'cancel clicked
    Exit Sub
    End If
End With

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sItem)


Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet
For Each tbl In sh.ListObjects
      With tbl.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
         .SortFields.Add Key:=tbl.ListColumns("LINK TO FILE").Range, _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Next tbl


i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'select cell
    Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)).Select
    'create hyperlink in selected cell
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        objFile.Path, _
        TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
    i = i + 1
Next objFile

Set objFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Update:

Code below on how to add filenames after lastrow with data. Just having trouble on only adding new filenames. So if filename exists in the table, skip file.

```
'loops through each file in the directory
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
Last = LastRow(sh)
    'select cell
    Range(Cells(Last + 1, 1), Cells(Last + 1, 1)).Select
    'create hyperlink in selected cell
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        objFile.Path, _
        TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
Next objFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Few ways you could do it. Since you've already figured out how to add the filenames to the bottom of the existing list, perhaps the easiest would be to do that, then use excels built in 'remove duplicates' function to eliminate the duplicated records.

Alternatively, before you add each record to the end of the list, you can check whether it's already in the list, and if it is, don't add it. eg:

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
Last = LastRow(sh)
    'select cell
    Range(Cells(Last + 1, 1), Cells(Last + 1, 1)).Select

    'Check if it's already in the list
    alreadyThere = false
    for i = 1 to range("A5000").end(xlup).row
        if range("A"&i).value=objFile.Name then
            alreadyThere = true
            exit for
        end if
    next i

    if not alreadyThere then
        'create hyperlink in selected cell
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
            objFile.Path, _
            TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
    end if

Next objFile
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like it will work. Or a manual way would be to add new batched items into its own folder. Thanks